# Tailwind cdn and isntallation npm not constistant

Tags: tailwind-css

To quickly start learning how to use tailwind, I added CDN link to my project. Once I had understood the basics, I decided to configure tailwind with webpack.

I created everything from scratch with all the configuration files and pasted the html code from the previous attempt. When I ran the code, it turned out that the pages do not look identical, after configuring some classes are missing and some elements have different property values.

In both cases I use newest version.

Examples:

```css
/* with cdn */
html {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.p-2\.5 {
  padding: .625rem;
}
```

```css
/* with configuration */
html {
  line-height: 1;
}

body {
  margin: 8px;
}

.p-2\.5 { /* doesn't exist */ }
```

My tailwind config file look like this, there is rather not many things that I can made wrong:

```js
/* tailwind.config.js */

module.exports = {
  future: {
    removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
    purgeLayersByDefault: true,
  },
  purge: [
    './templates/**/*.php',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

I also tried with file generated by command, but the result was the same - difference in both pages.

```
npx tailwindcss init --full
```

Why there are differences between CDN and configuration. Can I somehow configure my project to make it look like the one using CDN?

Comment: Are the TailwindCSS versions the same between them?

Comment: I think so.. tailwind on my dev is configured with version 2.1.0 and cdn use ```@^2``` so I believe it is also the newest version..

Answer (score 3):

#### Using Tailwind via CDN

Before using the CDN build, please note that many of the features that make Tailwind CSS great are not available without incorporating Tailwind into your build process.

- You can't customize Tailwind's default theme
- You can't use any directives like @apply, @variants, etc.
- You can't enable additional variants like group-focus
- You can't install third-party plugins
- You can't tree-shake unused styles

To get the most out of Tailwind, you really should [install it as a PostCSS plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#installing-tailwind-css-as-a-post-css-plugin).